# in add row function how to validate data on blur event in jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my example for validate data in jquery if user skip any textbox at that time
    i want to give alert on blur problem is i am using clone(add row) so i can't give alert
    on that in add row function.
 i do not know how to validate data in add row..

**jquery function**

```
function checkdata(txtObj)
{

  var row      = $(txtObj).parents('.itemRow');
  var weight   = row.find('.weight').val() ? row.find('.weight').val() : 0;
  var bag      = row.find('.bag').val() ? row.find('.bag').val() : 0;

  if(weight !== null)
  {
    alert("Enter Net Weight");
  }

  if(bag !== null)
  {
    alert("Enter One Bag Weight");
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantBhatt/Lvp34v4L/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creationg a attribute inside the tag, try creatin a jQuery function like this:

```
$('.weight').blur(function() {
    alert("Enter Net Weight");
});

$('.bag').blur(function() {
    alert("Enter One Bag Weight");
});
```

Comment: O maybe you can create a generic function with a `.alert` class and use the `if else` logic you used.